# Tensorflow, What is the best way to arrange tensors dimensions?

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

I am using tensorflow to train an RNN model.  I store my input tensors with the shape (Batch Size, Time Steps, 128) where the 128 is the length of the one hot encoding to represent ASCII characters.  To input a time step into an RNN I use the following function to reshape it to (Batch Size, 128)...

```
def getTimeStep(x, t):
    return tf.reshape(x[:, t, :], (-1, 128))
```

I am wondering if this is the most efficient way to feed my RNN the time steps.  I am not sure about how memory is ordered in tensorflow.  Here is the rest of my code for a sequence-sequence encoder.  Notice that I am saving the output after each timestep since I want to feed it into an attention model in my decoder.  Could I be doing something more efficiently?

```
input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, 128), 'input_tensor')
expected_output = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, (BATCH_SIZE, TIME_STEPS, 128), 'expected_output')

with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as encode_scope:
    encoder_rnn = rnn.MultiRNNCell([rnn.GRUCell(1024)] * 3)
    encoder_state = tf.zeros((BATCH_SIZE, encoder_rnn.state_size))
    encoder_outputs = [None] * TIME_STEPS
    for t in range(TIME_STEPS):
        encoder_outputs[t], encoder_state = encoder_rnn(getTimeStep(input_tensor, t), encoder_state)
        encode_scope.reuse_variables()
    encoder_outputs = tf.concat(1, [tf.reshape(t, (BATCH_SIZE, 1, 1024)) for t in encoder_outputs])
```

Comment: Please pay attention to how you tag these tensorflow questions. They clearly have nothing to do with CUDA programming (even if tensorflow itself might use CUDA intenally for acceleration). It is getting a bit tedious retagging *every* question you ask to remove the CUDA tag.

Comment: I don't see any obvious inefficiencies with your code. In a lot of cases though, performance will be very dependent on your hardware, data, and exact model, so I recommend digging into that with tools like tensorflow/tools/benchmark to find out more.